Evaluate $\int x 3^{x^2 - 1} \ dx$
In the textbook Apex Calculus II - Late Transcendentals, University of North Dakota adapted by Gregory Hartmann, there is the following:
Exercise 17/p. 359: Evaluate the indefinite integral $$\int x 3^{x^2 - 1} \ dx.$$
I get $\frac{3^{x^2-1}}{2 \ln 3} + C$, but the textbook answer gives $\frac{1}{2} e^{x^2-1} + C.$
I have no idea why.
Thanks in advance.

Well, we're not going to be able to tell you where your process is wrong without you showing your work.

That said, your answer appears correct (Wolfram agrees), and the answer does not differ from a constant from that in the textbook (Desmos), so I imagine this is a mistake on the textbook authors' part.

The book is wrong

Reverse engineering, the most likely explanation is that the problem is a misprint, and $~\displaystyle \int x ~e^{x^2 - 1} ~dx~$ was intended.  Beyond the fact that my hypothesis fits the facts, also consider that there isn't much additional educational value in $~\displaystyle \int x ~3^{x^2 - 1} ~dx,~$ because it is very straightforward to interpret this as $~\displaystyle \int x ~e^{\ln(3) ~[x^2 - 1]} ~dx.$

Everything points in the direction of a misprint.
Thank you all!
